# Ethereumj client and go-client

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumj

I started exploring the both the clients (go client and the EthereumJ) and saw the folder structure both of the client generates are so very different. For example the go client would have the following directory structure

```
databasedir\chaindata
databasedir\dapp
databasedir\nodes
...
```

However the java client has the following structure

```
databasedir\block
databasedir\details
databasedir\state
....
```

What it could mean that we can't swap between the clients? Is my understanding correct?